# CSS - border-radius doesn't display in IE6/7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, css, vendor-prefix

I'm using the following CSS to achieve a rounded border on my DIV:

```
border: 1px solid #999; 
border-radius: 6px; 
-ms-border-radius: 6px; 
-moz-border-radius: 6px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
```

But in IE 6/7/8, even though I'm including the IE specific radius, it is not displaying a rounded DIV border (it's displays a square border).

Any ideas why only IE 6/7/8 doesn't display a rounded border?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of IE8, IE doesn't support the CSS3 border-radius property. Not sure what you saw that said it did. You can use images, javascript, or many other tricks to round corners in IE.

Comment: You can use CSS3Pie to support that even in IE including IE6: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: IE9 supports border-radius (*without* any prefixes, like -ms): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162890/which-border-radius-property-will-work-in-ie9

Answer (score 4):

there is no -ms-border-radius internet explorer doesn't support it.

The 'newest' thing microsoft has to say about rounded corners is [this old table+images hack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413(VS.85).aspx) titled 'Staying Ahead of the Curve' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support border-radius.

From [IE8 Expert Zone Chat](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/expertzone/chats/transcripts/09_0122_ez_ie8.mspx):

> Chris Wilson [MS] (Expert):
>
> Q: [9]
>   Any plans to support CSS'
>   border-radius, eg.
>   -ms-border-radius:5px; ? Firefox and Safari have -khtml- and -moz-
>   implementations which we can use to do
>   rounded corners without images or
>   sprites, and improve performance ie.
>   http://preview.tinyurl.com/9y3tfn/
>
> A:
>   border-radius is high on the wish
>   list, but will not be in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

While I realise that an answer's been accepted, I wanted to suggest -if you need further advice/support/guidance- that you have a look at [Curvy Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/); they have a JS library with examples.

As, of course, do [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), albeit with a third-party (so far as I could tell) module from [phat fusion](http://www.phatfusion.net/roundedcorners/). And [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has its own third-party corner plugin, from [methvin](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner.html).