# Which border radius property will work in IE9?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, which border radius property will work?

```
 border-radius:20px
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
```

`border-radius:20px` or `ms-border-radius:20px`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IE9 will support `border-radius` see: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/01BorderRadius/Default.html

Comment: Link is broken, but [CanIUse says `border-radius` works for IE9+](http://caniuse.com/border-radius)

Answer (score 7):

border-radius will work. In fact MS made a big deal about how they're the only browser that actually supports the 'standards' while all the other vendors uses specific prefixes.

/me rolls eyes.

Comment: Opera supports border-radius too, Microsoft isn't the only one that doesn't use prefixes. :-)

Comment: You mean Microsoft isn't the only commercial vendor of closed source browsers to make stuff up. :p

Answer (score 4):

If you're reading this page then may also wish to consider include `khtml-border-radius` for compliance with Konqueror so it looks like:

```
 -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius:20px;
```

Comment: You should always add the W3C official one `border-radius: 20px` last. It shouldn't be the first in the list. So when the browser is updated to support the standard one then it will use that over the prefixed one.