# How we can enable border-radius in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

```
<style>
   border-radius:10px;
</style>
<div class='radius'> <?= echo $score . 'score';?></div>
```

It is not working in IE8

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - border-radius help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285014/css-border-radius-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is not supported in IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html). If you want it to work in IE8 you need to [use a hack](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser).

Comment: +1 Border radius is only supported in IE9 and later versions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Answer (score 5):

Border-Radius is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-8, in IE 9 use border-radius:10px.

It can work with Jquery or  [PIE CSS](http://css3pie.com/)

In **HTML** add jquery.js and jquery.corner.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.radius').corner();
```

For border-radius: 10px use

```
$('.radius').corner("10px");
```

for more examples: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/vTXXD/

Comment: I know that plugin works. I have seen it before, and it is a pretty nice plugin. However, it is not the only option. PIE CSS works too. So jquery is not the **only** option.

Comment: but your first comment is "That is not true"

Comment: I was saying that it is not true that jquery is the only option. Hence I said that you can use tools such as PIE CSS.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported prior to IE 9. You need to use something like [PIE CSS](http://css3pie.com/). This will require you to add a htc file within your site and your css will look something like this:

```
.radius {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` is a CSS3 property and IE8 doesn't support it (anything below IE8 doesn't have support for it).

However, there's a brilliant script called [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) which adds support for IE8.