# Round cornered panel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, css

I want to add round cornered panels in GWT. I found one solution here http://css3please.com/ 
, but it is not working with IE8. Any other workaround except DecoratorPanel ?

Thanks

Comment: I've no idea about `GWT`, but there's a polyfill for IE8 and below. Did you have any chance to take a look at [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: Its not working with IE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285014/css-border-radius-doesnt-display-in-ie6-7-8), border-radius isn't supported by IE8. That post has alternatives you can try.

Comment: with GWT , I am not able to achieve expected result using those solutions.

Comment: Use [CSS3 pie](http://css3pie.com/). Check off "Enable Pie" and "Show CSS" in that site. You'll see that they use a CSS property called: `behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);`. Download that `PIE.htc` file from their site, and host it with your project in order for it to work. Don't forget to fix the URL so it matches your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the old way using [cobogw](https://code.google.com/p/cobogw/) library. Check if rounded corners [demo](http://cobogw.googlecode.com/svn/demo/WidgetsDemo.html#RoundedPanel) fits for your needs.

Comment: No,GWT won't support it.